# Dafny question: How to sort the Dutch Flag problem with four colors?

Tags: testing, dafny

I'm trying to sort the Dutch Flag problem with 4 colors instead of 3, it seems that Dafny does not really verify and I could not fix it as well. This is my code:

```
datatype Colour = RED | WHITE | PINK | BLUE
method FlagSort(flag: array<Colour>) returns (w:int, p:int, b:int)
ensures 0 <= w <= p <= b < flag.Length
ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < w ==> flag[i] == RED
ensures forall i :: w <= i < p ==> flag[i] == WHITE
ensures forall i :: p <= i < b ==> flag[i] == PINK
ensures forall i :: b <= i < flag.Length ==> flag[i] == BLUE
ensures multiset(flag[..]) == multiset(old(flag[..]))
modifies flag
{
    var next := 0;
    w, p := 0, 0;
    b := flag.Length;
    while next <= b
    invariant 0 <= w <= p <= next <= b <= flag.Length
    invariant forall i :: 0 <= i < w ==> flag[i] == RED
    invariant forall i :: w <= i < p ==> flag[i] == WHITE
    invariant forall i :: p <= i < next ==> flag[i] == PINK
    invariant forall i :: b <= i < flag.Length ==> flag[i] == BLUE
    invariant multiset(flag[..]) == multiset(old(flag[..]))
    {
        if flag[next] == RED {
            flag[next], flag[w] := flag[w], flag[next];
            w := w + 1;

            if p < w {
                p := p + 1;
            }
            if next < w {
                next := next + 1;
            }
        } else if flag[next] == WHITE {
            flag[next], flag[p] := flag[p], flag[next];
            p := p + 1;
            next := next + 1;
        } else if flag[next] == PINK {
            next := next + 1;
        } else if flag[next] == BLUE {
            b := b - 1;
            flag[next], flag[b] := flag[b], flag[next];
        }
    }
    
}
```

Can anyone help me with this please, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution to this problem (you might be solving a hard problem !), but here is some relevant advice for each of the three errors Dafny found in your code.

## Error 1

When you see this:

```
flag[next], flag[b] := flag[b], flag[next];
                ^^^ index out of range
```

you can add an assertion before like this:

```
assert 0 <= b;
assert b < |flags|;
flag[next], flag[b] := flag[b], flag[next];
```

Magically, the index out of range will go away, and in your case, the first assertion will fail. You can then [apply verification debugging techniques to move the assertion up.](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-verification-debugging).

## Error 2

```
    while next <= b
    ^^^^^ cannot prove termination, try supplying a decreases clause
```

the problem is that it tried to insert the decrease clause `b - next`, which should always be decreasing and bounded below by zero. If you make it explicit, and hover the decreases expression, it will tell you "the decreases expression is always bounded below by zero", but you get a new error:

```
while next <= b
^^^^^ decreases expression might not decrease
    decreases b - next
```

What you can do is add this line at the beginning of your while loop.

```
ghost var b_saved,next_saved := b, next;
```

and at the end of your while loop, add the decreases check explicitly:

```
assert b - next < b_saved-next_saved;
```

You'll see that now the decreases clause is verified, and you have an error on an assert, on which you can apply regular [verification debugging techniques](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-verification-debugging).

## Error 3

```
if flag[next] == RED {
   ^^^^^^^^^^ index out of range.
```

Similarly, you can insert the implicit assertions there:

```
assert 0 <= next < flag.Length;
if flag[next] == RED {    // No error there
```

You'll see an underline on `next < flag.Length`. What can you do to ensure this? Perhaps change an invariant?